# Is it possible to delete useless links on friendly portals?

Tags: ingress

I've come across portals with a lot of links that don't provide much benefit as far as creating a field go, and the portal was maxed out for link capacity (8 inbound and 8 outbound max links allowed).  Is it possible to delete some of the useless links to that the portal can be linked elsewhere?

I'm assuming not since I can't find a way to, and I imagine this would cause issues for AP since people could just destroy and recreate links to keep getting the same AP bonuses over and over again.  But I thought I'd ask just in case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to destroy own faction link, field or resonator (yet).

You can let the resonators decay, this will only takes 9 days if nobody recharges or attacks the portal and it will destroy all existing links.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Very few portals where I am in Portland, OR ever decay since there's a lot of active people here, but that's good to know how long it takes to decay.  At least that's how long it takes if Niantic isn't doing mass forced decays on fields as part of their beta adjustments.

Comment: With the introduction of refactor viruses it is actually possible now to destroy your own faction's links. The answer should be updated.

Answer (score 22):

It is now possible to delete friendly links.

With the introduction of the *ADA Refactor* and *Jarvis Virus* items, you can change faction ownership of a portal by using the appropriate object on any portal (provided you have enough XM): such action destroys all links and fields connected to it.

This works even for friendly portals, so, if you flip a portal from your faction to the opposing one, you can destroy its links (and then eventually re-capture the portal and recreate only the links you need).

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit for ingoing links and there have never been. The star record is higher than 5000 ingoing links on one single portal like this operation in May 2015:

.